# matlab local static variable

Tags: matlab

In order to test an algorithm in different scenarios, in need to iteratively call a matlab function alg.m.

The bottleneck in alg.m is something like:

```
load large5Dmatrix.mat
small2Dmatrix=large5Dmatrix(:,:,i,j,k)  % i,j and k change at every call of alg.m
clear large5Dmatrix
```

In order to speed up my tests, i would like to have `large5Dmatrix` loaded only at the first call of alg.m, and valid for future calls, possibly only within the scope of alg.m

Is there a way to acheve this in matlab other then setting `large5Dmatrix`  as global?

Can you think of a better way to work with this large matrix of constant values within alg.m?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [persistent](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/persistent.html) for static local variables:

```
function myfun(myargs)
    persistent large5Dmatrix
    if isempty(large5Dmatrix)
        load large5Dmatrix.mat;
    end

    small2Dmatrix=large5Dmatrix(:,:,i,j,k)  % i,j and k change at every call of alg.m
    % ... 
end
```

but since you're not changing `large5Dmatrix`, @High Performance Mark answer is better suited and has no computational implications. Unless you really, really don't want `large5Dmatrix` in the scope of the caller.

Answer (score 3):

When you pass an array as an argument to a Matlab function the array is only copied if the function updates it, if the function only reads the array then no copy is made.  So any performance penalty the function pays, in time and space, should only kick in if the function updates the large array.

I've never tested this with a recursive function but I don't immediately see why it should start copying the large array if it is only read from.

So your strategy would be to `load` the array outside the function, then pass it into the function as an argument.

[This note](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-15SO4/?solution=1-15SO4) may clarify.

Comment: you are suggesting to change alg.m so that `large5Dmatrix` is loaded and given as an input by the testing script which calls alg.m? This would make the whole thing a bit less intuitive, and `large5Dmatrix` is part of the logic of the algorithm that i am testing, but I'll go for it if no other solution comes up! Thanks